# Move subdocument to another document

Tags: mongodb

I'm modelling a mongodb database that will have categories and articles.

The most common use will be listing articles through the categories, so I plan to make the articles as subdocuments of categories:

//db.categories.find()

```
[{
  "id": 01,
  "name": "Some category",
  "articles: [{
    "article_id": 01,
    "title": "",
    "content": ""
  }]
}]
```

Sometimes, I might be moving articles from one category to another.

In a relational database, I should just update a foreign key, but in the above case, how can I move an article to another category?

Some details:

- Preferable, the internal `ObjectId` should remain the same. But it's not mandatory.
- Article might also contain subdocuments, if so, they must come along when moving.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to get the article, then remove (pull) the article from its current category and then add (push) it into its new category, like this:

first get the article (*article_id:01*) from the category with *id:01* ...

then pull the article with *article_id:01* from the category with *id:01*

```
db.categories.update(
    {"id" : 01, "articles.article_id" : 01},       // query
    {"$pull" : {"articles" : {"article_id" : 01}}} // pull
)
```

and then push that same article (*article_id:01*) into its new category with *id:02*,

```
db.categories.update(
    {"id" : 02},                                   // query
    {"$push" : {"articles" : {                     // push
                              "article_id": 01,
                              "title": "",
                              "content": ""
                             }
               }
    }
)
```

if you want the array in the new category to be sorted after the push you have to use *$each* and *$sort* ([see here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort)).

For more info on *$pull* [check here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and for more info on *$push* [check here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Comment: What you're doing here appears no different than a `$set` and `$unset` operation, aside from the fact that you're operating on arrays. I think it's worthwhile to note that: A. Once the article is pulled, its data is removed, and B. the pull is just a manual insert into the array. I would imagine the OP wanted to move articles programatically, not copy pasting mongo inserts. I could be mistaken however.